# Audio Player with Play All Capability

Tags: jquery, audio, audio-streaming, html5-audio, soundcloud

I've been hunting around for a jQuery plugin that plays audio in the browser, and can automatically play the next audio file once the previous one is finished. Also, the ability to play only one audio file at a time; so if the user is playing one audio file, and clicks play on another, the first audio file should stop playing. In essence, I'm looking for something similar to how sounds are played on a page on SoundCloud. I've been looking at packages like SoundManager2 and jPlayer, but it doesn't look like they can do this.

So in bullet points:

- once one audio file is done, auto-start the next one
- only one audio file plays at a time; so, if an audio file is playing and the user clicks play on another, the first one should stop playing.

Any suggestions would be awesome, even if it's just pointing me in a general direction.

Comment: [WhatHaveYouTried](http://WhatHaveYouTried.com) We are volunteers who want to help you with a specific problem. We donate our time; donate some of yours and show that you at least tried something

Comment: Point taken. Changed wording. Next time, spare the condescending diatribe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SoundManager2 can do everything you're asking for, [see here](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/page-player/).